# Is the possible to load PPT/PPTX (powerpoint) file into FabricJS canvas?

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to implement some editing tool using canvas with FabricJS.
Is there any existing javascript library can extract from PPT/PPTX content and convert to canvas compatible object.

Comment: File conversions like that are best handled through a third party service. I'd recommend Filestack -  https://www.filestack.com/products/file-transformations/

Comment: Thanks @melchiar , but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: i am looking the same, have you found the solution?